# How to add a symbol to a group depending on its data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can I do the following depending on `d.Status!==""` were d belongs to the data(sortedFeatures)

```
feats = cont.selectAll('feats')
            .data(sortedFeatures)
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
                d['y'] = (fontsize * i);
                d['x'] = self.x_scale(d.start);
                return 'translate(' + self.x_scale(d.start) + ',' + fontsize * i + ')';
            }).attr('type', 'featureGroup');

polygonLastDelivery = feats.append('g');

polygonLastDelivery.append("path")
      .attr("class", "point")
      .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("cross"))//I don't want to add this symbol if d.Status==="" can I make a function out of this? 
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + 15 + "," + 22 + ")"; });
```

That is I want to add a symbol to the newly created group "polygonLastDelivery" depending on if 
.data(sortedFeatures) each contains a status text or if its empty. How whold you solve this?

I tried the following above whitout success

```
.attr("d", function(d) { return d3.svg.symbol().type("cross");})
```

Comment: Filter your selection based on the `Status` attribute, then add the symbol to the filtered selection.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a filter like this:

```
polygonLastDelivery.append("path")
    .filter(function(d) { return d.status !== "" })
    .attr("class", "point")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("cross"))
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + 15 + "," + 22 + ")"; });
```

Or you could use each if you want to change your symbol based on status:

```
polygonLastDelivery.each(function(d){
    var object = d3.select(this);
    var symbol = (d.status !== "") ? 'cross': 'diamond';
    object.append("path")
        .attr("class", "point")
        .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type(symbol))
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + 15 + "," + 22 + ")"; });
});
```